# How could I add cookies to this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Okay, so I have this code that manipulates a certain area to show different content boxes at the click of a link. I would like to be able to add cookies that would allow me to keep the selected content showing from one page to the next.

```
 /* code written by kismet of RPG-Directory.com */
$(function () {
    function selectTab(tab) {
        var i = 1;
        while ($('#tab' + i).length) {
            if (tab.attr('id') !== 'tab' + i) {
                $('#tab' + i).removeClass('highlight');
                $('#tab' + i + '-content').hide();
            }
            else {
                tab.addClass('highlight');
                $('#tab' + i + '-content').show();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    $('#tab1').addClass('highlight');
    $('.clickable').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            selectTab($(this));
        });
    });
});
```

I realize that this would probably be best done using an external file. I hope that the fact that the original code is not mine won't cause a problem.

Comment: have you tried any code ?

Comment: I had not because every time I play with cookies I end up causing problems. I am not above learning how and why they work, but I seem to be missing something obvious when I try to code from scratch. Micheal Geary's answer did solve my problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need to support IE7, you may want to consider using `localStorage` instead of cookies. It's much easier to work with:

```
localStorage.currentTab = i;

i = localStorage.currentTab;
```

Comment: IE7 is not really important, since it is mainly fluff in any case. I had to do some research to figure out exactly where in the code to place this string, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I love the idea of not having to use cookies!

Answer (score 0):

you can set cookies with jquery via https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie library.

Comment: Thank you for this link! It has actually helped me to figure out why I haven't been able to get cookies to work properly for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
document.cookie = encodeURI("helloworld") + "=" + encodeURI("from console");
```

you can also do this like this:

```
document.cookie = "hello=world"
```

Comment: Thank you for this information; however, I mainly have trouble relating these strings to specific codes.